# How to create a subset from a variant column in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, sql-variant

For example, suppose my variant column "xyz" consists of data like this:

```
{
  "post_new_visits": "Repeat",
  "post_new1_week": "Thursday",
  "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "post_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "post_new4_channel": "5.0",
  "pre_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "pre_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "pre_new4_channel": "5.0"
}
```

I want a new variant column from above variant column, which should only have "post*" key values, something like below,output should be like this.

```
{
  "post_new_visits": "Repeat",
  "post_new1_week": "Thursday",
  "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "post_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "post_new4_channel": "5.0",
}
```

Is there any way i can acheive this?

Comment: There is a code format option in the question editor - I recommend you use it.

Comment: it's in Snowflake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can flatten and re-construct the JSON. For example:

```
create table tmp ( v variant )
as 
select
    parse_json(
        '{  "post_new_visits": "Repeat",
          "post_new1_week": "Thursday",
          "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
          "post_new3_site": "12:50AM",
          "post_new4_channel": "5.0",
          "pre_new2_appt": "Weekday",
          "pre_new3_site": "12:50AM",
          "pre_new4_channel": "5.0"}'
    )
union all                              
select
    parse_json(
        '{  "post_new_visits": "New",
          "post_new1_week": "Friday",
          "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
          "post_new3_site": "13:50AM",
          "post_new4_channel": "4.0",
          "pre_new2_appt": "Weekday",
          "pre_new3_site": "14:50AM",
          "pre_new4_channel": "2.0"}'
    );                                      




select
    OBJECT_AGG(v2.key, v2.value)
from
    tmp,
    lateral flatten(input => v) v2
where
    v2.key like 'post%'
group by
    v2.seq;
```

Comment: The solution is working for one value(given as a parameter in parse_json) but its not working  for all the column values, i meant cant apply for a table

Comment: Do you have multiple variant columns or multiple rows? It should work for multiple rows (all table).

Comment: with tmp as (
    select
        parse_json(variant_column) v from table_name
)
select
    OBJECT_AGG(v2.key, v2.value) as persisted_vars
from
    tmp,
    lateral flatten(input => v) v2
where
    v2.key like 'post_evar%'
group by
    v2.seq;

Comment: If we use flatten, it's giving a huge performance impact for example, in my case, I have around 500 key-value pairs and a million records also, so performance is too low, is there any other way instead of flattening, I mean UDF's, SP's.

Comment: FLATTEN/OBJECT_AGG is indeed quite slow. But you can always write a JavaScript UDF doing exactly what you want.